# Tell Webpack Where to Find Static Assets in Vue Application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I recently switched to the Vue 3 CLI.  After using creating a Vue project I installed webpack and then added the following file to my project's base directory:

vue.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        plugins: [
            new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
                maxChunks: 1
            })
        ]
    },
    chainWebpack:
    config => {
        config.optimization.delete('splitChunks')
    }
}
```

My goal is to make custom elements using this great module: https://github.com/karol-f/vue-custom-element.  It seems to work as intended, but when I run npm run build, all hrefs in my index.html file link to the root directory (`href=/css/app.11f77a6e.css`), so the browser looks in places like:

```
`file:///C:/css/app.11f77a6e.css`
```

How can I configure Webpack so that links to resources are relative and looked for in the `dist` folder?

I've tried adding a webpack.config.js file to my project's root with the following:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    }
}
```

But it didn't help.

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "build-flow",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.21",
    "vue-custom-element": "^3.2.6",
    "webpack": "^4.28.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.3.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21"
  }
}
```

Comment: @tony19  Awesome, thanks that worked.

Comment: Sure, no problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing `file:///` URLs implies that you're not viewing the files through a dev server. You're probably opening up `index.html` directly (e.g., by double-clicking `index.html`). If that's the case, you need to start up a server in `dist`, and navigate to it from your browser:

1. Open a Terminal, and CD into `<project_root>/dist`.
2. Run [`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html), which should print out something like `Serving on 0.0.0.0 port 8000`. Make note of the port number for the next step. (Alternatively, run [`http-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server))
3. Open a browser, and navigate to `http://localhost:8000`.